# Where attachments of Steps are stored in VSTS REST API?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the Python REST API of VSTS for TFS / Azure Dev Ops (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api).

I would like to add attachments to some of the steps of my Test Cases like I can do in the Web Interface.

This is how I want my step to look like:

[image: Step with attachment]

... and when you run it, that would look like this:
[image]

However, I have not been able to find where this information is stored.

This is the JSON data for the WorkItem of my Test Case

```json
{
id: 224,
rev: 2,
fields: {
    System.AreaPath: "GM_sandbox\GM-Toto",
    System.TeamProject: "GM_sandbox",
    System.IterationPath: "GM_sandbox",
    System.WorkItemType: "Test Case",
    System.State: "Design",
    System.Reason: "New",
    System.AssignedTo: "Jeff",
    System.CreatedDate: "2019-01-03T01:43:09.743Z",
    System.CreatedBy: "Jeff",
    System.ChangedDate: "2019-01-03T02:12:07.15Z",
    System.ChangedBy: "Jeff",
    System.Title: "Titi",
    Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate: "2019-01-03T01:43:09.743Z",
    Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate: "2019-01-03T01:43:09.743Z",
    Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy: "Jeff",
    Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority: 2,
    Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus: "Not Automated",
    Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps: "<steps id="0" last="2"><step id="2" type="ValidateStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Click on the rainbow button&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;P&gt;Screen becomes Blue (see picture)&lt;/P&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>"
},
_links: {
    self: {
        href: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCT/23d89bd4-8547-4be3-aa73-13a30866f176/_apis/wit/workItems/224"
    },
    workItemUpdates: {
        href: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCT/_apis/wit/workItems/224/updates"
    },
    workItemRevisions: {
        href: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCT/_apis/wit/workItems/224/revisions"
    },
    workItemHistory: {
        href: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCT/_apis/wit/workItems/224/history"
    },
    html: {
        href: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCTi.aspx?pcguid=4107d6a2-eaaa-40b9-9a8d-f8fdbb31d4b7&id=224"
    },
    workItemType: {
        href: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCT/23d89bd4-8547-4be3-aa73-13a30866f176/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Test%20Case"
    },
    fields: {
        href: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCT/23d89bd4-8547-4be3-aa73-13a30866f176/_apis/wit/fields"
    }
},
url: "https://my_server.com:8443/tfs/PRODUCT/23d89bd4-8547-4be3-aa73-13a30866f176/_apis/wit/workItems/224"
}
```

Any idea on where this information is stored?

And, if you are familiar with the Python REST API, how to add an attachment from a file and link it to the test step?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The steps would probably be through the API:
1. Add the attachment
2. Create a link to the attachment on the work item, make sure the comment is [TestStep=x] where x is the test step you want it to display on.

Comment: @Matt,. this is an intersting idea. When adding the attachment in the step via the Web Interface, there is indeed a comment starting by "[TestStep=x]:" next to the file attached. However, just adding the attachment with this comment does not work. What type of Link are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the flow using just the azure-devops-rest-api

[Create the attachment:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#upload_a_text_file)

**Request:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=info.txt&api-version=4.1
```

**Body:**

```
{"User text content to upload"}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "id": "f5016cf4-4c36-4bd6-9762-b6ad60838cf7",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/attachments/f5016cf4-4c36-4bd6-9762-b6ad60838cf7?fileName=info.txt"
}
```

[Create the Work Item:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

**Request:**

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test Case?api-version=4.1
```

**Body:**

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample test case"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
    "value": "<steps id=\"0\" last=\"4\"><step id=\"2\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;test&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step><step id=\"3\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;test&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step><step id=\"4\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;test&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
        "rel": "AttachedFile",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/attachments/f5016cf4-4c36-4bd6-9762-b6ad60838cf7?fileName=info.txt",
        "attributes": {
            "comment": "[TestStep=3]:",
            "name": "info.txt"
        }
    }
  }
]
```

The test case that is created will look like the below.  There is something off with the step numbering for the number in the comment.  Looks like it need to be +1 for the actual step you want to reference.

[image: TFS TestCase]

The key is to have in the attributes of the attached file, the **comment** with `"[TestStep=3]:"` as well as a `name` for the attachment.

---

In **Python**, that would give something like this:

1. Creating of attachment with function `create_attachment`
2. Updating a Test Case with `url`, `comment`, and `filename`

So something like that...

```
from vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.models.json_patch_operation import JsonPatchOperation

def add_attachment(wit_id: int, project: str, url:str, comment: str, step = 0, name = ""):
    """Add attachment already uploaded to a WorkItem
    """
    # For linking the attachment to a step, we need to modify the comment and add a name
    if step:
        attributes = {
            "comment":f"[TestStep={step}]:{comment}",
            "name": name if name else re.sub(r".*fileName=", "", url)
        }
    else:
        attributes = {"comment": comment}

    patch_document = [
        JsonPatchOperation(
            op="add",
            path="/relations/-",
            value={
                "rel": "AttachedFile",
                "url": url,
                "attributes": attributes,
            },
        )
    ]
    return client.wit.update_work_item(patch_document, wit_id, project)

attachment = client_wit.create_attachment(stream, project, 'smiley.png')
add_attachment(tcid, project, attachment.url, 'Attaching file to work item', step=3)
```

Comment: I was so close... What I just needed was to add the name of the file in the attributes (I was just adding the comment). Thanks a lot!